# power query reverse data propagation

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Suppose I have a big master table with columns: product, type, price, and note.
type includes: Fruit, Vegetable
I would like to create a filtered table for Fruits only in a separate sheet SF.
So far it is easy.

I would like to be able to edit notes in the sheet SF and require that changes are propagated to the master table.
Do you please know a way to do so? (power query is not necessary if you know another solution)

Best wishes
L.

Comment: That is probably not gonna work in Excel. And it looks like that this is a task for a real database and not for Excel. Excel is to calculate sheets not to use as a database therfore smart people invented real databases. If you choose the right tools it should be possible.

Comment: As far as I understand, you are trying to implement this: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/